# How can I multiply matrices by overloading the * operator, when the operator doesn't match the operands?

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading, matrix-multiplication

I have two matrices which should multiply together by overloading * operator in the constructor class, but the problem here is that no `operator []` matches these operands. Why?

I saw videos and asked my classmates multiple times and tried my own way, but I can't make it work. I only get this error!

This is the code I have a problem with:

## The Constructor Code:

I made two ways to make this code works. The result should store at cell matrix or the new matrix:

```
Matrix operator*(const Matrix &matrix1, const Matrix &matrix2)
  {
    if (matrix1.Cols != matrix2.Rows) {
        throw("Error");
    }
    cell.resize(matrix2.Cols); // one way to call 
    Matrix res(matrix1.Rows, matrix2.Cols, 1.0); // second way to call
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.Rows; i++) {
        cell[i].resize(matrix1.Rows);
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix2.Cols; j++) {
            double value_of_elements;
            for (int k = 0; k = matrix1.Cols; k++) {
                res[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[i][j];// 
   1. metod
                value_of_elements += matrix1[i][k] * 
    matrix2[i][j];// 2. metod
            }
            cell[i][j]+=value_of_elements;
        }
    }
    return res;
   }
```

## The Header Code:

The header code normally I don't have unless some modification should be made.

```
friend Matrix operator*(const Matrix &matrix1, const Matrix &matrix2);
```

## The source Code:

This is where the code is tested:

```
try {

        Matrix m1(3, 3, 1.0);
        Matrix m2(3, 4, 1.0);

        std::cout << "m1*m2:" << m1 * m2 << std::endl;// this si where the matrix should be multiplied here;

    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "!" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Unknown exception caught!" << std::endl;
    }
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

## The result:

The result should be this:

```
m1*m2:[3, 3, 3, 3
3, 3, 3, 3
3, 3, 3, 3]
```

What I get is an error; the cause of error are that `res[i][j]`, `matrix1[i][k]` etc. have operators [] wont work on these operands:

```
Error   C2065   'cell': undeclared identifier 71  matrix.cpp
Error   C2065   'cell': undeclared identifier 74  matrix.cpp
Error   C2065   'cell': undeclared identifier 81  matrix.cpp
Error   C2088   '[': illegal for class 79   matrix.cpp 
Error   C2088   '[': illegal for class 78   matrix.cpp  
Error   C2676   binary '[': 'Matrix' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator  78  matrix.cpp
Error   C2676   binary '[': 'const Matrix' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator    78  matrix.cpp
Error   C2676   binary '[': 'const Matrix' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator    79  matrix.cpp
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "cell" is undefined  71  Matrix.cpp
Error (active)  E0349   no operator "[]" matches these operands 78  Matrix.cpp
Error (active)  E0349   no operator "[]" matches these operands 78  Matrix.cpp
Error (active)  E0349   no operator "[]" matches these operands 78  Matrix.cpp
Error (active)  E0349   no operator "[]" matches these operands 79  Matrix.cpp
Error (active)  E0349   no operator "[]" matches these operands 79  Matrix.cpp
```

Comment: Apparently, your `Matrix` class does not provide `operator[]`. What part of the error message do you find unclear?

Comment: Does the class `Matrix` has a member containing the values? For example, if you have a member `vector<vector<double>> cell`, you can access it using `res.cell[i][j]`. If you write `res[i][j]`, the compiler expect to find an operator [] declared in the class Matrix itself.

Comment: ok, ill try this...

Comment: Also, the function is not a member of a class. If `cell` is part of the object `res`, you always need to write `res.cell`.

Comment: Ok know it works, but here is the second problem, the matrix goes out of scope...

Comment: What do you mean by "out of scope"?

Comment: @ZainAhmed -- *the matrix goes out of scope* -- You really need to post what your `Matrix` class consists of.  Is it based on pointers and dynamically allocated memory?  Does it use `std::vector`?  All of this information is important, as you are returning a `Matrix` by value in your `operator *`, and if `Matrix` does not have the correct copy semantics, none of this will work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the class matrix has a member `vector<vector<double>> cell`, here is a sample that multiply matrices:

```
Matrix operator*(const Matrix &matrix1, const Matrix &matrix2)
  {
    if (matrix1.Cols != matrix2.Rows) {
        throw("Error");
    }
    Matrix res(matrix1.Rows, matrix2.Cols, 1.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.Rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix2.Cols; j++) {
            double value_of_elements=0;
            for (int k = 0; k = matrix1.Cols; k++)
                value_of_elements += matrix1.cell[i][k] * matrix2.cell[k][j];
            res.cell[i][j]=value_of_elements;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

There was three problems. First the class `Matrix` doesn't have an operator[]. The problem was solved by accessing the member `cell` directly. Second, the variable `value_of_elements` was not initialized, making the result undefined. Third, the matrix multiplication was not done correctly. You multiply one column from `matrix1` with one column from `matrix2`, whereas you should multiply a row by a column.

Comment: When you solve your problem, please put it as an answer. It tells people that they don't have to solve the problem again when they don't have to.

Comment: where do i put it?

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer here:

```
Matrix operator*(const Matrix &matrix1, const Matrix &matrix2)
{
    if (matrix1.Cols != matrix2.Rows) {
        throw("Error");
    }
    Matrix res(matrix1.Rows, matrix2.Cols, 0.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.Rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix2.Cols; j++) {
            double value_of_elements;
            for (int k = 0; k < matrix1.Cols; k++) {
                res.cell[i][j] += matrix1.cell[i][k] * matrix2.cell[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: There is a mistake in the indices, as explained in my answer. Instead of "m1[i][k]*m2[i][j]", it should be "m1[i][k]*m2[k][j]".

Comment: This answer does not explain what the problem was, so it will be very difficult for the next person with this problem to use this answer. Please add some text to explain what changed and why.

Comment: @ZainAhmed StackOverflow questions comes from individual problems, but also serves as a Question&Answer database to help other people to solve similar problem. This is why it is important to answer your own question when you find the solution yourself, but also to answer with all the necessary details needed for others to understand how you solved it.